# C# Linq to XML getting of parent and child objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read in an XML file and then to populate the values into C# classes (parent and child objects). I have left out a lot of the code for brevity. I am trying to accomplish this via Linq to XML.

I created the following class which will be the parent class that will also host a list of child string objects:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<string> Options { get; set; } = new();
    public FieldType Type { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

So a field can have 1 of 2 things:

1. It can have an empty list of string options
2. Or it can have a list of string options

The XML was done in a funny way, I cannot change it, I just have to read it in and populate the classes and string objects (if any) and return this list to the front end for further processing.

The XML file in simplified form:

```
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Question 1</FieldName>
    <FieldType>1</FieldType>
</FieldProperties>
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Dietaries</FieldName>
    <FieldType>9</FieldType>
</FieldProperties>
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Question 2</FieldName>
    <FieldType>1</FieldType>
</FieldProperties>
<FieldProperties>
    <FieldName>Transport</FieldName>
    <FieldType>9</FieldType>
</FieldProperties>
<FieldOptions>
    <FieldName>Dietaries</FieldName>
    <Option>Dietary option 1</Option>
</FieldOptions>
<FieldOptions>
    <FieldName>Dietaries</FieldName>
    <Option>Dietary option 2</Option>
</FieldOptions>
<FieldOptions>
    <FieldName>Dietaries</FieldName>
    <Option>Dietary option 3</Option>
</FieldOptions>
<FieldOptions>
    <FieldName>Transport</FieldName>
    <Option>Transport option 1</Option>
</FieldOptions>
<FieldOptions>
    <FieldName>Transport</FieldName>
    <Option>Transport option 2</Option>
</FieldOptions>
```

A field class is represented by the `FieldProperties` tag. To determine if a field has options, you need to check if it has a `FieldType` of 9. If the `FieldType` is 9 then you have to go and look for `FieldOptions` and this is linked to the `FieldName` tag of the `FieldProperties` tag.

I do not know how to write such a query. What I currently have is to loop through all the `FieldProperties` and then to populate the field properties. But I do not know how to check if the field type is 9 and if it is 9, then to go and get a list of `FieldOptions` child objects and then to populate the Options properties.

This is what I currently have:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlFields);
XNamespace xNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/FieldDefinition.xsd";
List<Field> fields =
    xDocument.Descendants(xNamespace + "FieldProperties")
        .Select(fieldProperties => new Field
        {
            Name = (string)fieldProperties.Element(xNamespace + "FieldName")!.Value,
            Type = (FieldType)Int32.Parse(fieldProperties.Element(xNamespace + "FieldType")!.Value)
        }).ToList();

return fields;
```

Comment: Fetch all `FieldOptions` as a list first, then foreach through fields, if its `Type` is 9, get all `FieldOptions` that has same name with it, and set the `Options` field then.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = xDocument.Root
                      .Elements(xNamespace + "FieldProperties")
                      .Select(fp => new Field {
                          Name = (string)fp.Element(xNamespace + "FieldName"),
                          Type = (FieldType)int.Parse(fp.Element(xNamespace + "FieldType")!.Value)
                      })
                      .GroupJoin(
                          xDocument.Root.Elements(xNamespace + "FieldOptions"),
                          f => f.Name,
                          fo => (string)fo.Element(xNamespace + "FieldName"),
                          (f, fo) => new { Field = f, Options = fo })
                      .SelectMany(x => 
                          x.Field.Type == FieldType.Options
                              ? x.Options.Select(o => new { x.Field, Option = (string)o.Element(xNamespace + "Option")! }) 
                              : new { x.Field })
                      .GroupBy(x => x.Field)
                      .Select(g => 
                      {
                          var field = g.Key;
                          if (field.Type == FieldType.Options)
                          {
                              field.Options = g.Select(x => x.Option).ToList();
                          }
                          return field;
                      })
                      .ToList();
```

1.GroupJoin to match Fields to their corresponding Options

2.SelectMany to flatten into a stream of {Field, Option} pairs

3.GroupBy Field to consolidate the Options